# Not able to append elements to list in PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compare rows of a table and record the values where change has occurred in PySpark within DataBricks environment.
I created an empty list and trying to append items to list when a change has occurred.
The problem is, when I found a change and inserting into the list, I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Here is a rough snippet of the code. This is not the exact code I am using.

```
def compare_rows(df):
     df = df.toPandas()
     changes = []
     if df.col_x != df2.col_y:
         changes.append(col_x)
     return changes
```

I converted df to Pandas DataFrame for my convenience.
The error is occurring when I am trying to append elements to the list *changes*. Upon some research I found that this may due to Py4j conversions occurring in PySpark, between Python and Java collections. I am not entirely sure of this.
Also I am not getting this error, when I don't implement this as a function.
Can someone please help me figure out this please?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a slightly different approach here , other than what you performed,
The best way to compare each and every row in spark is to join both the dataframe with each and every column based on the **`primary_key`** and get the resulted output - Below code snippet to explain on the process

## Create the Dataframe here

```
df_left = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"chicago","USA", "US", "US"),(2,"houston","USA","US" , "US"),(3,"Sydney","Australia","None","AU")],[ "id","city","country","region","continent"])
df_right = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"chicago","USA", "USA", "USA"),(2,"houston","USA","US","US"),(3,"Sydney","Australia","None","AU")],[ "id","city","country","region","continent"])
df.show()
+---+-------+---------+------+---------+
| id|   city|  country|region|continent|
+---+-------+---------+------+---------+
|  1|chicago|      USA|    US|       US|
|  2|houston|      USA|    US|       US|
|  3| Sydney|Australia|  None|       AU|
+---+-------+---------+------+---------+

+---+-------+---------+------+---------+
| id|   city|  country|region|continent|
+---+-------+---------+------+---------+
|  1|chicago|      USA|   USA|      USA|
|  2|houston|      USA|    US|       US|
|  3| Sydney|Australia|  None|       AU|
+---+-------+---------+------+---------+
```

## Rename the right dataframe column first so that you have all the columns from both the dataframe

```
df_right = df_right.withColumnRenamed("id", "right_id").withColumnRenamed("city", "right_city").withColumnRenamed("country", "right_country").withColumnRenamed("region", "right_region").withColumnRenamed("continent", "right_continent")
df_result = df_left.join(df_right, (df_left.id == df_right.right_id) & (df_left.city == df_right.right_city) &  (df_left.country == df_right.right_country) & (df_left.region == df_right.right_region), "left")
+---+-------+---------+------+---------+--------+----------+-------------+------------+---------------+
| id|   city|  country|region|continent|right_id|right_city|right_country|right_region|right_continent|
+---+-------+---------+------+---------+--------+----------+-------------+------------+---------------+
|  1|chicago|      USA|    US|       US|    null|      null|         null|        null|           null|
|  2|houston|      USA|    US|       US|       2|   houston|          USA|          US|             US|
|  3| Sydney|Australia|  None|       AU|       3|    Sydney|    Australia|        None|             AU|
+---+-------+---------+------+---------+--------+----------+-------------+------------+---------------+
```

## Now, if you want to see the transaction whihich was not matched from the right side dataframe , just filter out the null id column

```
df_result = df_result.filter(F.col("right_id").isNull())
df_result.show()
+---+-------+-------+------+---------+--------+----------+-------------+------------+---------------+
| id|   city|country|region|continent|right_id|right_city|right_country|right_region|right_continent|
+---+-------+-------+------+---------+--------+----------+-------------+------------+---------------+
|  1|chicago|    USA|    US|       US|    null|      null|         null|        null|           null|
+---+-------+-------+------+---------+--------+----------+-------------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I can't do this, as I have more than 100 columns to compare. But Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In my production code we have 140+ column and this process ensure the correctness and brings confidence.. as this an one time activity.. Will really appreciate if you could accept and upvote the answer if the solution / approach helped you ..

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't answer my actual question. I already have a code which does the comparison. And I need that as a reusable code.

Comment: Well in that case you can create a function and push the solution and call the function wherever you need